# ReactJS Material UI Typescript - withStyles warning

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I keep getting this warning, although my styling is applied as I want:

> Failed prop type: Invalid prop `classes` of type `function` supplied
>    to `WithStyles(App)`, expected `object`.
>        in WithStyles(App)

```
import React from "react";
import {
  CssBaseline,
  Theme,
  createStyles,
  Paper,
  Typography,
  withStyles,
  WithStyles,
  withTheme
} from "@material-ui/core";

const styles = (theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    layout: {
      width: "800",
      marginLeft: theme.spacing(2),
      marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
      [theme.breakpoints.up(800 + theme.spacing(2) * 2)]: {
        width: 800,
        marginLeft: "auto",
        marginRight: "auto"
      }
    },
    paper: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
      marginBottom: theme.spacing(3),
      padding: theme.spacing(2),
      [theme.breakpoints.up(800 + theme.spacing(3) * 2)]: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(6),
        marginBottom: theme.spacing(6),
        padding: theme.spacing(3)
      }
    }
  });

interface AppProps extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {
  classes: any;
}

class App extends React.Component<AppProps> {
  constructor(props: AppProps) {
    super(props);
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    classes: styles
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <CssBaseline />

        <main className={this.props.classes.layout}>
          <Paper className={this.props.classes.paper}>
            <Typography component="h1" variant="h4" align="center">
              Sub Head
            </Typography>
            Hello World
          </Paper>
        </main>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default withTheme(withStyles(styles)(App));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The props interface should be extended refer to official [document](https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/)

```
import {
  WithStyles,
  withStyles,
  withTheme
} from '@material-ui/core';

interface Props extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {
  classes: any,
  ...
}

class YourComponent extends React.Component<Props, State>{
  ...
}

export default withTheme(withStyles(styles)(YourComponent));
```

#### Update

You don't need to set default Props from styles

```
  static defaultProps = {
    classes: {},
  }
```

would be fine. Guessing the error came from here

Comment: nope that doesn't cut it :( https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-br6qys